# Валидация по размеру текста Laravel

Tags: laravel

Могу ли я в текстовом поле сделать валидацию по весу текста? (например 100кб).

Comment: Зачем такое извращение, если не секрет?)

Comment: Такова задача :)

Comment: Если принципиальна проверка текстового поля по "весу", то необходимо перед валидацией записать это поле в файл, а уже потом этот файл проверять на валидацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посчитать, 1 символ = 1 байту (тут на всякий случай кодировку нужно смотреть), то получаем, что 1Кб = 1024 байта, тогда если в условии стоит 100Кб, то получаем 100*1024 = 102400 байт или 102400 символа, тогда в валидаторе можно прописать следующее правило

```
'text' => 'max:102400'
```

По данной логике, можешь реализовать свое правило с теми рассчестами, которые показал выше, и сделать что-то подобное:

```
'text' => 'maxKb:100'
```